# Should or Must in Java file name

Tags: java, class, class-names

I'm learning about Java and have just encountered 2 instructions:

1. A class **must** have a matching filename
2. Remember that the name of the java file **should** match the class name

Ask:

*Should* in (2) ***LIKE*** or ***DIFFERENT*** *Must* in (1) ?? ->  (1), (2).

What is correct ??

Comment: This isn't a technical question. By convention the java filename matches the classname and it helps in identifying which class lives where. Also if this is a homework problem, this will get you no where.

Comment: I just want it is Obligatory or not

Comment: Try it... Try to create a class `Node` and store it in a file named `Note.java`, then try to compile it.

Comment: This site's purpose is to help with objective questions in programming. Read [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Then try `public` vs non-`public` classes that match and don't match the filename.

Comment: Then recognize that just because some *compilers* have rules about this, there's no reason other than convention for those compilers' rules. Mentioned briefly in the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6

Comment: thank you everyone for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not as clear as it might seem at first, partly because the JLS does not require packages to be stored in a file system:

[7.6. Top Level Type Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6) :

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>   [...]

So your answer is basically:

It *may* be a "must", depending on your compiler.

Comment: Have my vote for A) putting up JLS content and B) leaving some room for other answers.

Answer (score 2):

To be fully precise:

- A **public** class X must sit in `X.java` (see the nice answer by user Hulk for this "must")
- Beyond that, non-public classes Y, Z *should* live in `Y.java` and `Z.java`, but they *can* also go into X.java

The Google coding standard for example emphasizes that second rule. You are supposed to have one top level class per file, and then the class name should match the file name.

Doing anything else is most likely going to confuse any experienced Java programmer. And confusing your readers is always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!!. I'll apply that rule. I just want to know more about it

Comment: As said, then please accept one of the answers :-)